# Scanning two or more docs on HP Envy 5530 causes WSOD

Tags: printing, printer

I scanned two documents. I said "Yes" after the first one and it froze and displayed the White Screen of Death whilst flashing all lights. How do I fix this? This error is on the printer itself, not on a PC.

Printer  HP Envy 5530

Windows 10 OS

Comment: Have you tried power cycling it again and try to scan the documents again?

Comment: Make and model of Printer and OS would be helpful

Comment: @Moab Can't tell the Printer OS, but the printer is HP Envy 5530.

Comment: The OS you are printing from, Windows ???

Comment: @Moab Printing from WIndows 10. The PC has no errors.

Comment: Did you install the latest printer driver and Firmware from HP?>>>>https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-envy-5530-e-all-in-one-printer-series/5304881/model/5304882

Comment: @Moab The firmware is up-to-date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124700/discussion-between-54657-and-moab).

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the printer to factory defaults.

[This Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2fpLbRpKaM) shows how to get into the service menu of an Envy 5530 and how to get to resets. However, it seems quite complicated.

I found another [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vekl13qoW8U) for a printer with a different front panel. In that video, the printer is shown as an "Envy 5000 series". From the front panel, you select Setup > Tools >  Restore Factory Defaults. I mention this because, in the first video, the 5530 display shows that there is a second menu page (the 2 dots at the bottom of the display). See if that can get you into Setup on your printer; it would be much easier than the first video.